# Unboxing struct type C#

Tags: c#, unboxing

I am C# learner . I encountered with the delema . When I am unboxing (object variable into int variable  and I encounter the error) . My code:

```
namespace test1
{
    public struct Tst 
    {

        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var v1 = new Tst();
            v1.x = 5;
            Object o1 = v1;
            Tst ll = (Tst)o1;
            ((Tst)o1).x = 10;  // here I have an error. I cant understand why I cant do it.
            Console.WriteLine(ll.x);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error I see is: "Cannot modify the result of an unboxing conversion"

Comment: An object is a reference, a value is well a value. So your trying to access something referenced as a value. But, you can assign the cast reference to a value and then use it. A value is a value in memory while a reference is a pointer to the location.  Hmmm, see the answer Erik referenced.